# Way to load server generated image(takes a while to generate) asynchronously using Ajax

Tags: jquery, image-processing, jfreechart

Hey guys I've searched far and wide for this.  I'm trying to get a image that takes a while to generate to load asynchronously after the page/css/other images have loaded on the page.  This image is actually a chart generated using JFreeChart.  I want to go ahead and load the page but have the charts come in afterwards.  I thought I found the solution in my second example but this doesn't seem to work in IE8.  It just shows a red X.  It seems to work Ok in Chrome and Firefox.  I'm just wondering if there is a better way.  I've also tried this plug in.  This didn't seem to work either.

http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail

```
   /* $(function () {
        var img = new Image();
        $(img).load(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $('#loader').removeClass('loading').append(this);
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }).error(function () {

        }).attr('src', 'http://localhost/chart/3074/110/2011-05-15/2011-05-25');
    })
     */
    $(window).load(function() {     
        $("#test").load(function() {
            var img = this;
            $('.'+ID).fadeOut(function() { $(this).html(img); }).fadeIn();
        }).attr("src", 'http://localhost/chart/3074/110/2011-04-15/2011-05-25'); 
    });
```

Just remember this isn't a normal image.  It is generate on the fly in the server and then served to the page.  Thanks for your help.

```
$(window).load(function() {       

    var insertedTable =  $('#pkgLineTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,       
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": false,
        "sAjaxSource": '@{Overview.getPkgLineList()}',
        "fnServerData": fnServerObjectToArray(['shortname', 'description', 'lineStatus', 'statusStamp'])          
    });

    $('#test').attr('src', 'http://localhost/chart/3074/110/2011-04-15/2011-05-25');
    $('#test2').attr('src', 'http://localhost/chart/3074/110/2011-05-15/2011-05-25');
});   



<img src="/public/images/ajax-loader.gif" id="test"></img>
<img src="/public/images/ajax-loader.gif" id="test2"></img>
```

Comment: Are you accessing localhost in the default 80 port too? Maybe its a crossdomain issue

Comment: Are you using the right content type and MIME type for the response? IE seems to be pretty picky with that.

Comment: The IE issue maybe a MIME issue.  I'll look into that.  I know how picky IE can be after messing with server generated CSV sheets.  That was kind of a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need #test to load.  In fact, since you're calling this on window.load, #test.load will have already loaded, so you'll never get the event.

Here's the drop-dead simple version of what you want:

```
$(window).load(function() {     
    $('#target_image').attr('src', 'http://localhost/chart/3074/110/2011-04-15/2011-05-25');
});
```

Assumes an img already on the page, with an ID of 'target_image', potentially with no src attribute.

This can change depending on how your data is stored, what you want to do with it, etc.  Unfortunately, we don't have that context.

Comment: This is a dead simple way to do it.  The only problem is with multiple charts they are loaded in order so if the first one takes the longest it holds up the other ones.  This isn't true asynchronous loading right?  I also have other ajax calls on the page and depending on what order I put them in the window.load is the order they get loaded in.  Not ideal but if it's not possible I can live with it.  I've added some code to my original post.  In my code test takes much longer to load than test2.  Since test is first it holds up loading of test2.

Comment: All requests get fired, but your browser will do them simultaneously... there is nothing to guarantee that the first image will show up after the second, or even the 4th.  The same is probably true for your AJAX calls (without seeing them), it just appears that they are synchronous because the execution may be fast enough that the first call gets the first response.  Your datatable is build on window.load, which may be appropriate... but you may also consider moving it up to document.ready, which happens significantly sooner than window.load.

Comment: Oh, and as an added comment... if you're building charts with AJAX data, you might consider an AJAX chart.  IMO, the best one out there is HighCharts: http://www.highcharts.com/  I use this with dataTable a lot, the only trick is that you'll need to write a translator to move the data from one place to the other (as their basic data syntaxes are somewhat different).  Generally pretty lightweight though.  My own user testing (small sample) has shown that the Ajax charts were preferred 100% of the time, but the chart itself was a pretty major focus of the test.

Comment: Interesting.  The datatable was moved to window.load because it was a long running query also.  I didn't want to it hold up the rest of the page.

Comment: I'm actually using highcharts also.  We are providing static charts(Jfreechart) for people who are using older browsers.

Comment: Is it a bandwidth constraint, or a server constraint on the datatable?  It should only block other things if there's a bunch of data coming through the pipe. A couple of key things here: If you're pushing a lot of data, consider gzipping your AJAX output. If you can take snapshots in time (even, say, 5 minutes), I'd recommend something like memcached and using an Etag setup so that you can issue 304's. Store your data short-term (without going back to the DB) and send back 'not-modified' headers if a client asks for data again too quickly.  Would make subsequent load on pages nearly instant.

Comment: The data is presented in way it can't be cached.  It has to be presented new every time.  There are different date ranges they can select.  There could be a bottleneck at the Mysql level.  Not sure why that would block.

Comment: It doesn't block... My concern was that you add an extra megabyte download into the heap, things will get slow.  As far as caching, I expect it can be done.  You'd just set your keys based on the incoming parameters.  Simplest would be something like Memcache::set(md5($user_id.'_'.http_build_query($_GET)), $data, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 60).  This would be aware of the incoming parameters, and cache the data for 60 seconds... it really depends on your usage scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle and try to do the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/byM8g/2/

I think it will work ok